# iOS+OpenGL ES 2.0: Why are update() and glkView() not called by the GLKViewController?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, sprite, glkview

I am trying to run the [Ray Wenderlich sprite example](http://www.raywenderlich.com/9743/how-to-create-a-simple-2d-iphone-game-with-opengl-es-2-0-and-glkit-part-1). I have set up a GLKViewController and a GLKView and implemented the methods from the corresponding delegate protocol.

```
- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect { }

- (void)update { }
```

**But these methods are not called by the GLKViewController! Someone any idea what I am doing wrong?**

I already have altered the code to animate some bubbles from bottom to the top.

Please check out a clone from GitHub:

https://github.com/salocinx/SpriteTestOpenGL

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I had the following property defined in my category:

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) CGSize screen;
```

This somehow had overwritten a property from the GLKViewController. It's a shame that there's no warning for such case, this cost me more than an entire day...